# Google Sandbox2 for arm64

Tags: sandbox

According to ./sandboxed_api/sandbox2/regs.h only 64 bit Intel and 64 bit PowerPC architectures are supported.

```
#if !defined(__x86_64__) && !defined(__powerpc64__)
  static_assert(false, "No support for the current CPU architecture");
#endif
```

Can someone tell me why arm64 is not supported? 
Is it planned to be supported in the near future?

Comment: Which sandbox are you talking about? Have you tried asking the developers of this code about ARM support?

Comment: It is about Sandbox2 from Google. Unfortunately, the project page does not say anything about contacts. I hope the developers or someone porting the project reads stackoverflow.